# Binding CSV Data to SVG Drawing with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, csv, svg

I have started a scaled down, proof-of-concept floor plan application for my employer that is using an SVG floor plan drawing generated by Adobe Illustrator CC, HTML, CSS and AngularJS.

The idea is to have a floor plan that contains static cubicle/office numbers and to marry that floor plan with a CSV file with personnel data that updates periodically and make the information available on our intranet.

Although I am new at AngularJS/SVG, I was following an [example](https://medium.com/@tweededbadger/tutorial-dynamic-data-driven-svg-map-with-angularjs-b112fdec421d#.roolkkm1l) for a map of the US and have made some pretty good progress so far, however am now at a point where I need to map the CSV data (personnel) to the SVG (cubicles) and am not sure how to proceed.

From the example in the link above, the author appears to have injected an "sg-click" directive into the SVG DOM with Angular.$compile that fires a JS Alert() of the ID of the SVG DOM when clicked:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.elementId = element.attr("id");
        scope.regionClick = function () {
            alert(scope.elementId);
        };
        element.attr("ng-click", "regionClick()");
        element.removeAttr("region");
        $compile(element)(scope);
    }
```

I am wondering if the same thing is possible with the CSV data, IE:

1. Outer loop over the SVG (Cubicle ID)
2. Inner loop over the CSV (Personnel/Cubicle ID) data
3. If Cubicle ID matches Personnel ID, inject the CSV data into that SVG node.

Since I am having some difficulty including the functional code here due to tag and external file restrictions, I have created a [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/PN5h6ZUUPTISegbyWFnJ?p=preview), where you can view everything in context along with external files that is operational in its current state.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking with a colleague, he suggested that I:

1. Convert the CSV list into an array.
2. Load the array into some kind of container.
3. When a user clicks on a cubicle.
4. Iterate through the array and see if there's a match based on the cubicle ID.

Since this my first attempt at Angular, my implementation may well be incorrect, but I've created a new plunk to reflect the latest code changes.

```
...code in plunker.
```

Thanks.

[Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/qG67bzLxq7cPQkJ3Tedk?p=preview)